# Inspecting elements that hide quickly

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, code-inspection

I need to inspect a HTML element in a website but I'm not able to because the element hides really fast.

The element A appear when I hover an element B, when my cursor comes out of the element B, element A disappears. So I don't know how to find out it direct parent and I don't know if it's destroyed of hidden.

How do I do to inspect elements that hide fast ?

Comment: Are the elements removed from the DOM entirely, or are they just set to `display: none`?

Comment: I wish I could know :)

Comment: I mean It'd be great if we could stop events to be able to inspect whatever element we want at a very specific moment

Comment: Do you know how to make the element appear again? If so make it appear and inspect it, sometimes when you refresh the page the element will stay inspected so you can see what is happening to it when the page loads.  If you don't know how to make it appear, just inspect any element on the page and search for the element you want to inspect in the html and the click on the opening element tag and it will also inspect that element

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing the element is being removed using JavaScript? You can request Chrome to pause JavaScript execution when DOM is modified. Right click the element (the parent) in which the disappearing element is created and click on Subtree Modifications in the Break on... sub menu.

It doesn't have to be a direct parent. If you don't know the exact parent you could always use either the html or body element to break on.

[image: Screenshot of menu item]

After you've inspected the element, click on continue to continue JavaScript execution.

Comment: I don't know the it's parent since I can't have any information of it.

Comment: This feature is also available in Firebug. Right-clicking an element gives *Break On Attribute Change*, *Break On Child Addition or Removal* and *Break On Element Removal*.

Comment: @smarber I've edited the answer to explain that it doesn't have to be a direct parent. So if you don't know the parent, you could always use either the html or body element to break on.

Answer (score 2):

If the element display is toggled via JavaScript, you can investigate that by stopping the script execution when the DOM is modified.

In Firebug you can do that by right-clicking the element within the *HTML* panel and checking *Break On Attribute Change*, *Break On Child Addition or Removal* and/or *Break On Element Removal*.

[image: Break On Mutation options]

Answer (score 0):

A good way that I recently found **in Google Chrome** is to press <kbd>F8</kbd> button when the element is visible and the inspector panel is open, so the page execution pauses and you can inspect the God-damned element!