# How to edit a dev class that only appears on click on the devtools of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I have tried all of the list in the following picture, non activates the click behavior so I could edit the class that only appears on click.

[image]

I want to edit the style of the class that only appears on click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inspecting elements that hide quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968556/inspecting-elements-that-hide-quickly)

Comment: It didn't, I have tried the solutions there.. not what i want

Comment: You need to choose "attribute modifications" not subtree.

Comment: Yes solved using this @wOxxOm