# See all expanded elements in DevTools for a popup that will close immediately on click

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

I need to see all the elements in a Calendar popup for a DatePicker control which will close immediately on any outside click. Opening the calendar on the page populates DIV parent elements. In DevTools, I then need to drill down into those DIVs to see the styling on the child elements that just got created.

However, as soon as I click on the `> div` to expand it the popup will close. Is there a solution to this problem? I can use either Chrome or Edge.

[image]

In other words, some kind of Auto-Expand mode in DevTools would be great, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Press Ctrl-Shift-P and type `emfoc`, then Enter, to enable "Emulate focused page". See also [Inspecting elements that hide quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31968556)

Comment: You can try the methods provided by wOxxOm. If the problem persists, please share more details with us.

Comment: Yes the `emfoc` worked thanks!